# Conditional Expectation Greater than Constant

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, conditional-expectation

is it possible to show that for a constant $0<k<1$ that $\mathbb{E}[X | X>k] \geq k$?
Apologises if this seems obvious, probability theory is not my thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathbb{E}[X| X > k] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_{X|X>k}(x) dx = \int_{k}^{\infty} x f_{X|X>k}(x) dx \geq k \int_{k}^{\infty} f_{X|X>k}(x) dx = k$$
because the pdf for all values of $x$ when $x \leq k$ under the conditional distribution must be $0$.